# Is this method a mutator or accessor method?

Tags: java, syntax, mutators

I have the below method which returns true if a growth rate is less than 0 or false otherwise. I was wondering what kind of method it would be, mutator or accessor.

```
    public boolean endangered(double GR) {
    if (GR < 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It does not access or mutate any value — its a new value that is being returned, it seems, and will possibly be used somewhere.

Below is the full class, if that helps:

```
public class Species {

    private int population;
    private double growthRATE;
    private String speciesName;
    private String endangered;

    public Species() {
        speciesName = "Dingo";
        population = 1000;
        growthRATE = 0.6;
    }

    public Species(String name, int population, double GR) {
        name = name;
        population = population;
        growthRATE = GR;
    }

    //Mutator methods

    //accessor methods


    public boolean endangered(double GR) {
        if (GR < 0) {
            return GR < 0;
        } else {
            return GR < 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it mutate any state? Does it access any state? What do you conclude?

Comment: Note that it should simply be `return GR < 0;`

Comment: Consider giving the `GR` parameter a more meaningful name too.

Comment: @JBNizet I added

Comment: @neburRB I knew the answer to those questions. I asked them in order to make **you** think about it by yourself. You should be able to see, by yourself, that this method des not access any state, but only uses the argument that the caller provides. So since it doesn't mutate nor gives access to any state, its neither a mutator nor an accessor, by definition.

Comment: @JBNizet I thaught so so what is it then?

Comment: Your class has a `growthRATE` field already. Didn't you mean to check if _that_ field is `< 0` instead of getting it as a separate parameter?

Comment: Well because GR is shorter and will hold teh value of growthRate when I pass it in @Ivar

Comment: @neburRB **read** the comments and the answers. What is unclear in *it's neither a mutator nor an accessor,*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them. You doesn't mutate any instance and you don't return a field instance either.
Your method makes some logic, so you could say that it is a logic/business method.

Answer (score 2):

It is neither an accessor or a mutator. It doesn't rely on instance state, so it should be `static` (I would call it a *utility* method). And you can return the test without a branch like

```
public static boolean endangered(double GR) {
    return GR < 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying that it *should* be static. Maybe it's intended to be overridden. Maybe it implements an interface method.

Comment: @JBNizet If there were an interface in the question I'd be willing to concede the point, as is (without any instance state being used) it's at least debatable (and I feel it should be mentioned).

Comment: Method can be overriden in future so static may not be very good option to add.